# Angular update view after change data

Tags: angular

```
<div class="text">{{message}}</div>

private message = 'Some message';

ngOnInit() {
    this.setMessageToDisplay();
}   

       setMessageToDisplay() {
          if (this.packageService.isDocPackageEmpty) {
                if(this.router.url === '/documents/todo') {
                    this.message = 'M1';
                }
                else if (this.router.url === '/documents/done') {
                    this.message = 'M2';
                }
                else if (this.imageService.isVisiblePatientDocList()) {
                    let pacientId = this.router.url.split("/")[2];
                    this.message = "M3";
                }
            } else {
                this.message = 'Def Message';
            }
            return this.message;
        }
    }
```

Using {{message}} displayed intialize value of this variable despite value changed in method this.setMessageToDisplay(). I do something like this in html `<div class="text">{{setMessageToDisplay()}}</div>` but method is executed few time and I want display only last value of message variable. Is possible set {{message}} in html and refresh view ?

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke change detection manually with ChangeDetecorRef module :

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from @angular/core

constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.setMessageToDisplay();
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: <div class="text">{{message}}</div>  still display initialize value this variable

Comment: using console this.ref.detectChanges() is undefined

Answer (score 0):

just try this change:

```js
<div class="text">{{message}}</div>

public message = 'Some message';

ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.setMessageToDisplay();
}   

       setMessageToDisplay() {
          let message: string;
          if (this.packageService.isDocPackageEmpty) {
                if(this.router.url === '/documents/todo') {
                    message = 'M1';
                }
                else if (this.router.url === '/documents/done') {
                    message = 'M2';
                }
                else if (this.imageService.isVisiblePatientDocList()) {
                    let pacientId = this.router.url.split("/")[2];
                    message = "M3";
                }
            } else {
                message = 'Def Message';
            }
            return message;
        }
    }
```

REMEMBER to set `public` your message

Comment: This is probably good aproach but ngOnInit is executed only one even when i value routerLink changed

Comment: use `ngAfterViewChecked` or better `ngAfterContentChecked`

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

or :

```
get message() { return this.setMessageToDisplay(); }
```